# Compiling on linux with c++ standard libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compilation

Hi have the following example code:

**func.h** - header file for functions

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using std::vector;
using std::tuple;
tuple <double,double> A(vector<int>& n);
```

**func.cpp** - function cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
tuple <double,double> A(vector<int>& n)
{
  double a1=n.size();
  double a2=a1+0.5;
  return make_tuple(a1,a2);
}
```

**main.cpp** - main cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include "func.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   double a1,a2;
   vector<int> n;
   n.push_back(1);
   n.push_back(2);
   tie(a1,a2)=A(n);
   return 0;
}
```

This compiles well in visual studio.

I have a problem compiling it on Linux (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 Red Hat 4.4.7-11) with:

```
g++ -03 -std=c++0x main.cpp func.cpp -lm
```

It does not compile, I get the following errors:

```
1. In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/array:35,from main.cpp:5:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library suppcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

2. ‘std::tuple’ has not been declared

3. expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’ token
```

Any guidance on how to deal with this will be helpful!

Comment: gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)

Comment: Version 4.4 of GCC didn't support C++11 very well, barely any of it actually. If it's possible you should update GCC to a later version (it's now up to version 6.2, which has full support for C++11 and C++14, and much of the upcoming C++17).

Comment: I can't update it, it's an external server and the guy in charge won't do it... any other ways? icpc? anything else?

Comment: Then use pre-C++11 features, like `std::pair` or arrays or structures. And use some other environment to learn modern C++.

Comment: Double check your compilation command. It has some typos. it may be related or not to your problem. ``` -o b -std=c++0x ``` instead of ``` -o -std=c++0x b ``` and ```-O3``` instead of ```-03```

Comment: Install a *modern* GNU/Linux distribution, such as CentOS6 *minimum* (equivalent to RedHat6) in a virtual machine in your own PC and ditch this "server guy" who continues to be stuck in back in 1997 (year RHEL4.x/5 were released), which is doing you a dis-service, IMHO.

Comment: I edited your original command (`g++ -o -std=c++0x b main.cpp func.cpp -03 -lm`) because it had some errors (wrong optimization option, unknown b file, missing aoutput)

Comment: Find a different service provider. Seriously. That particular compiler version is *four years old*, from a baseline *seven* years old. In C++ compiler terms, that's a dinosaur.

Comment: @eddie, indeed the order was wrong, I run it now with icpc: icpc -std=c++11 -o b main.cpp func.cpp, and it works well. any idea what is the main difference between the two compilers?

Comment: @jarhead  Have you tried with your gcc version and the right command? I don't use icpc.

Comment: @eddie, yes, it does'nt work, I'll stick with what works for now :)

Comment: @jarhead I suggest you to learn to use gcc. You will probably meet it very often if you stay in the software and it is free. Consider to compile your own gcc version directly from sources... if you have time ;)

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly the error seems to tell you that std=c++0x is not set.
Double check your compilation command. it should be

```
g++ -std=c++0x -o b main.cpp func.cpp -O3 -lm
```

and not

```
g++ -o -std=c++0x b main.cpp func.cpp -03 -lm
```

as in the original question.

Comment: One of the important differences between commands you didn't mention is that it's `-O3` (capital o, not zero).  The other difference being that `-o` takes the next argument as the output file name.

Answer (score 3):

You are telling GCC to output to the file named "-std=c++0x", and thus not setting that option at all, leading to this error. What it does with "b" afterwards, I have no idea. But you should always do "-o outputfilename" and not put other options between the "-o" option and its argument.

Answer (score 2):

I cut and pasted your three files (`func.h`, `func.cpp` and `main.cpp`) and I can assure you that on my Linux box (CentOS 7.2) with g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) everything works fine (your original command had some errors):

`g++ -o myProg -O3 -std=c++0x main.cpp func.cpp  -lm`

Update your GCC (even from sources if you have several hours ;) ) .

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to run an executable (compiled from recent [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) or [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) source code) on a server with an old version of Linux and of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) -you have [GCC 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/) which does not support recent C++ standards, because it appeared in 2009 before the publication date (2011) of C++11- you could try the following:

- install a recent Linux distribution on your own laptop (or computer) and check that its  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler is at least [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) (and preferably [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/)) by running `g++ --version` (you might need to use `g++-5` instead of `g++`, etc...)
- compile and link *statically* your program on that laptop using `g++ -static -std=c++14 -Wall func.cpp main.cpp -lm -o mybinprog` (and perhaps also `-O3` if you want to optimize and/or `-g` for debugging -better do the debugging locally-)
- copy (e.g. using `scp mybinprog remotehost:`) the executable to the remote server and run it there

It is very probable (but not certain) that a statically linked executable built on a newer Linux (laptop) would run on some older Linux server.

BTW, to compile a multi-source file program, better learn how to use [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Notice that order of program arguments to `g++` matters a big lot, so read the documentation about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

<sup>PS. Technically you might even try to link dynamically the C library and statically the C++ standard library.</sup>

Comment: The OP shows a linker error, you explain about runtime errors which might not even be relevant to the OP's situation (although I agree the recommendations are good, but not answer-worthy).

Comment: The OP does *not* show a linker error, but an error about language standard.

Comment: Right, compile error, not linker error. But what your answer says has nothing to do with the error message.